# fish prompt returns to defaults after change in fish_config

Tags: fish

I've been using Fish for a while and after installing Oh-My-Fish the prompt changed to the default OMF prompt. And I couldn't change to what I was using before, one of the default Fish prompts called "Sorin" and now I can't make any settings in Fish, even after reinstalling everything from scratch, the settings I make through the "fish_config" command don't take effect.